# How to convert .VOC to MP3 or other audio format?

Tags: audio, video, file-conversion, mp3

I am looking for a (free) way to transform .VOC files to, lets say, MP3?

I just found [Vidego](http://www.idealshare.net/video-converter.html), but I am not happy with the price of the software.

I have .VOC files and want to transform them to a more "standard" format. **Which ways are there to convert those files?**

Comment: Are they Creative Labs or RCA .voc files? (They're apparently completely different)

Comment: How can I find out?

Comment: Only way I can think is to try the [MediaHuman Audio Converter](http://www.mediahuman.com/audio-converter/) - freeware. If it can convert them, they're Creative Labs...

Answer (score 2):

`ffmpeg` is a free command line tool that can convert a huge number of audio and video formats including VOC files.

You can install it through [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) using the following command.

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

And then you can convert VOC files to MP3 like so.

```
ffmpeg -i sample.voc sample.mp3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got this error though: "aac @ 0x7fc483009400] More than one AAC RDB per ADTS frame is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented."

Comment: Do the MP3 files generated by ffmpeg sound okay? ffmpeg will throw up errors whenever it finds a problem. I see lots of messages like this when I convert files but almost all the time the generated files are okay. YMMV of course.

Comment: Nope, audio file is 296 bytes big and not working....

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [VideoLAN Converter](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.html) (VLC)? It's a well-known converter app for video and audio formats. [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net) is also a well respected audio converter app as well. They're both free, to boot. I've been using them for years.